# How to add new projection using ArcObjects of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I want to use "Mars MOLA" { 86 3396000.0 3396000.0 "Mars MOLA" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 } with my shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

v10 now supports [Well Known Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

You can also send your coordinate system details (.prj and information about the origins of it) to Esri Support to submit it as a new WKID.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a .prj file in your text editor (see shape file spec) then you can just copy that file into the Coordinate Systems folder in the ArcGIS Program Files folder. I did this for an old spatial reference.

Looks like there are some parameters for Mars MOLA here:
https://isis.astrogeology.usgs.gov/IsisSupport/index.php?topic=1527.0